# How do I give my image view padding below the navigation bar?

Tags: swift, uiimageview

[image: THIS IS WHAT IT LOOKS LIKE]

I would like there to be space in between the navigation bar and the image but it isnt seeming to work.
Any help would be much appreciated!  Here is my code:

```
addSubview(profileImageView)
profileImageView.anchor(top: topAnchor, left: self.leftAnchor, bottom: nil, right: nil, paddingTop: 75, paddingLeft: 95, paddingBottom: 12, paddingRight: 12, width: 180, height: 180)
profileImageView.layer.cornerRadius = 180 / 2
profileImageView.clipsToBounds = true
```

Here is declared variable:

```
let profileImageView: UIImageView = {
    let iv = UIImageView()
    iv.backgroundColor = .red
    return iv
}()
```

Comment: Can we see what is going on in your `anchor` function and a little more of the code so we can see what the `topAnchor` variable is / how its being set?

Comment: I used an extension to get the .anchor function.  Should I post it?

Answer (score 0):

```
    let topAnchor = self.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.safeTopAnchor, constant: 8)

    let rightAnchor = self.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.rightAnchor, constant: 0)

    let leftAnchor =  self.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leftAnchor, constant: 0)

    let heightAnchor = self.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 180)

    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([topAnchor!, leftAnchor!, rightAnchor, heightAnchor!])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use  Safe Area Guide is guide for Visibale Screen of your UIView exclude(Tabbar,NavigationBar..etc)

```
   self.view.addSubview(profileImageView)

    let safeAreaGuide = self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide //  Safe Area Guide is guide for Visibale Screen of your UIView exclude(Tabbar,NavigationBar..etc)

    // add bading using `constant`
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([self.profileImageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeAreaGuide.topAnchor, constant: 10),
                                 self.profileImageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 180),
                                 self.profileImageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 180),
                                 self.profileImageView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeAreaGuide.leftAnchor, constant: 95),
                                 self.profileImageView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeAreaGuide.rightAnchor, constant: -12),
                                  self.profileImageView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeAreaGuide.rightAnchor, constant: -12)])
```